# Ubuntu Belkin G Wireless connection problems

Tags: wireless-networking, ubuntu-9.10

I am on Ubuntu 9.10 Karmic and have a Belkin G Wireless router with WPA2 Personal Security. Whenever I try to connect, it keeps prompting for the password over and over.

Any ideas how to get the connection working?

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced this problem countless times using KDE.

Try removing your driver (modprobe -r [driver]) and then reloading it, then try to restart NetworkManager.

Also if your AP has security try disabling it and then accessing it non-securely.

Answer (score 0):

I also had bad experience with those wireless adapters. I have a N access point, and although I had no major issues connecting from my Linux netbook, my wife, under Vista, was getting disconnected all the time. I bought a standard D-Link N adapter, and the problem went away.